# Let $X$ be a normal space then there exists a continuous map $f : X → [0, 1]$ such that $f^{−1} (0) = A$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a normal space with the property that every closed set in $X$ is a countable intersection of
open sets in $X$. Then show that given $A \subset X$ closed, there exists a continuous map $f : X → [0, 1]$ such that $f^{−1} (0) = A$

Also, Given $A, B ⊂ X$ closed, $∃$ a continuous map $f : X → [0, 1]$ such that  $f^{−1} (0) = A$ and  $f^{−1} (1) = B$

Comment: Every closed set in $X$ is a countable intersection of *open* sets? Are you sure or is this a typo?

Comment: It is not an inherent property. I am sure it is right.

Comment: Do you know Urisohn's Lemma?

Comment: @5xum Is it? The property doesn’t say that the closed sets in $X$ are *exactly* countable intersections of open sets, so there might be countable intersections of open sets (such as trivial ones) that aren’t closed, right?

Comment: @k.stm Oh, I see now. My bad.

Comment: @Crostul I thought of it. But it talks about TWO disjoint subsets.

Answer (score 0):

If $A = \bigcap_{n\ge 1} U_n$ is a countable intersection of open sets, then for al $n\ge 1$ you can apply Urisohn lemma to $A$ and $X \setminus U_n$. There exists a function $f_n:X \longrightarrow [0,2^{-n}]$ such that $f_n(A)=0$ and $f_n(X\setminus U_n)=2^{-n}$.

Then $f=\sum_{n \ge 1} f_n$ is your required function.

Comment: You probably need to say a thing or two about why $f$ still is continuous.

Comment: Can you give me a hint to prove the second part of the question

Comment: @Qbit: Call Crostul’s function $f_A$. Define a similar function $f_B$ for $B$. Now consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{f_A(x)}{f_A(x)+f_B(x)}\;.$$

Comment: How can I argue about the continuity of f?

Comment: @Qbit: It’s a (complicated) composition of continuous functions: $f_A$, $f_B$, addition, and division by non-zero values. (You have to ping me with `@Brian` if you want to be sure that I see the comment; yours here went to Crostul, not to me.)